# Случайные записи из таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица объявлении и нужно получить записи в случайном порядке.

Comment: Да и на стаковерфлоу с десяток подобных вопросов просто по слову "случайный" в катагории [mysql] ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой вид запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY rand();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT* FROM объявлении ORDER BY RAND()
```